# iPhone how to take data from xml over the network

Tags: iphone

I have two questions.

1. I have my data in XML format on web server. How can i connect it and use that data.
2. Is this secure? Can i use it in professional application?

Thanks for any sort of advice in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get xml file from url:

```
NSMutableString *serverURL = *xml url here*;
NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverURL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSData *responsedata = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. My second question. Is this secure to apply for business application?

Comment: I'm sure others can jump on that question, I'm not an expert on it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it secure?  It depends on how secure you need.  If you're just transferring generic data, it doesn't really need to be secure.  If you're transferring sensitive or personal data, then you need to (at minimum) use a secure SSL connection and some sort of authentication scheme.